# LibGDX - Rotating sprites and still keep the positioning between them

Tags: java, libgdx, sprites

I've been struggling with a problem regarding rotations and relative positions between sprites (in this case, the sprites are just lines) - a bit off-topic, but should i be using the ShapeRenderer class to do this, though?

Anyway, it might be quite simple but i can't seem to figure it out properly. Heres a picture of the situation: https://gyazo.com/78988e07991fedc778eaeb70f8a04d8e

Now, after trying a bunch of different approaches, this piece of code is the one i'm testing right now:

`   public class TestState extends AbstractGameState {

```
private static final String LINE = "lineEffect.png";

private Sprite[] sprites;

public TestState(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);

    sprites = new Sprite[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        sprites[i] = new Sprite(new Texture(LINE));
        // both lines starting at the same X and Y
        sprites[i].setPosition(20, 50);
        // both lines have the same size
        sprites[i].setSize(100, 2);
        // guess i might be messing up here
        sprites[i].setOrigin(sprites[i].getX(), sprites[i].getY());
    }

    // for testing purposes
    sprites[0].setRotation(-20);
    sprites[1].setRotation(45);
}

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    for (Sprite sprite : sprites)
        sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}`
```

Any help on this would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Returns the function "sprites[x].getX()" its corner X coordinate? If not, the origin should be set on it's corner point to get the correct rotation;

Comment: @AhmetZambak i'm not sure if that's what you're asking, but sprites[x].getX() returns 20, wich is the X value i applied in the line before. I thought that, by starting there, the X value wouldn't be moddified, just the sprite's rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the origin to a line edge:

```
// guess i might be messing up here
sprites[i].setOrigin(0, 0);
```

It depends on real line location in lineEffect.png.

Comment: thank you for the answer! Setting the origin to (0,0) was the solution. Thanks you very much! :)